# On radical finite generation of the maximal ideal of a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, local-rings

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a local ring such that $\mathfrak m$ is not finitely generated.

Then, must it be true that $\mathfrak m$ is not the radical of a finitely generated ideal ?

I am mostly interested in the case when $R$ is either a Valuation ring https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring 
or a ring of prime characteristic $p>0$ which is Perfect (i.e. $R$ is reduced and $R=\{r^p : r \in R \}$ ) .

Note that if $(R, \mathfrak m)$ is a Valuation ring such that $\mathfrak m$ is not finitely generated then $\mathfrak m =\mathfrak m ^2$ .

Please help.

Comment: Consider a pair $(A,\varphi)$ where $A$ is a ring and $\varphi : A \to A$ is a ring morphism. Take $R := \varinjlim (A \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} A \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} \dotsb)$ in the following cases: (1) $A$ is a DVR of characteristic $p$ and $\varphi$ is the Frobenius; (2) $A = k[[t]]$ for a field $k$, and $\varphi$ sends $t \mapsto t^{2}$.